# How can I add a span tag inside my menu link?

Tags: 8, theming, navigation

My twig file contains the following:

```
<li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
   {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
</li>
```

Which outputs:

```
<li class="menu-item item--search">
    <a href="#search" title="Expand Search" data-drupal-link-system-path="&lt;front&gt;">Search</a>
</li>
```

But I really want to add a `<span>` tag around the text `Search` (for styling purposes and replacing the text with an icon image.

I tried replacing `{{ link(item.title, item.url) }}` with `<a href="{{item.url}}"><span>{{item.title}}</span></a>` but that loses valuable attributes provided by the `link` function (as well as the menu_link_attributes module). I'm not sure if I can do this in twig or I need to write some sort of function in my `.theme` file. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
{% set tmp = '<span>'~item.title~'</span>' %}
{% set link_text %}{{ tmp|raw }}{% endset %}
{{ link(link_text, item.url) }}
```

Comment: For my purpose this was the easiest to implement and achieve the desired result - it also allows me to target specific menus and not apply it to all links.

Comment: Actually the elegant solution is to use {% set %} and {% endset %}, so you can write html between the tags.

Comment: For those of you wondering what @QuanLee is talking about: `{% set link_text %}<span>{{ item.title }}</span>{% endset %}`

Answer (score 2):

For adding markup to all links, you could implement [hook_link_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_link_alter/8.5.x) in a custom module (in the following example named `mymodule`):

```
use Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup;

/**
 * Implements hook_link_alter().
 */
function mymodule_link_alter(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['options']['span_added'])) {
    return;
  }

  $variables['text'] = new FormattableMarkup('<span>@title</span>', [
    '@title' => $variables['text'],
  ]);

  $variables['options']['span_added'] = TRUE;
}
```